# Gradle:Add same module as dependecy to other modules

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have 3 modules(all 3 are library projects ) :
`A,B,C`

I want to refer to `B` as a dependecy in `module A` and `module C`.
The *app* module has A,B and C as a dependecy.

Since this is an Android project I would expect it to be something like:

### Module A

```
//    A/build.gradle

//remaining config
compile project(':B')
```

and

```
//    A/settings.gradle

include ':B'
```

### Module C

```
//    C/build.gradle

//remaining config
compile project(':B')
```

and

```
//    C/settings.gradle

include ':B'
```

### app

```
//    app/build.gradle


//remaining config
compile project(':A')
// dependecy for module B is not needed since I would get the same set of APIs from A and B
compile project(':C')
```

and

```
//    app/settings.gradle

include ':A',':C',':B'
```

My question is:
how is this internally handled.Would there be any code duplication involved.
Is there a better way to handle such dependecies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
-root
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--libA
|----build.gradle
|--libB
|----build.gradle
|--libC
|----build.gradle
|--app
|----build.gradle
```

In the `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':libA',':libB',':libC', ':app'
```

In the `libA/build.gradle` and `libB/build.gradle`:

```
compile project(':B')
```

Otherwise, if any libA, libB, libC are separate projects:

1. use a Maven repository to distribute your libraries
2. use an external path in the settings.gradle

In the option 1. you should use a **maven repository** (you have to publish the library in a private or public maven repo).
In this case, gradle downloads the dependencies using the pom file which will contains the dependencies list.

In the `libA/build.gradle` and `libB/build.gradle`:

```
compile 'myLibB:X.X.X'
```

In the option 2. use:

```
-rootApp
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--app
|----build.gradle

-rootLibA
|--build.gradle
|--settings.gradle
|--moduleA
|----build.gradle
```

Inside a project you can refer **an external module**.

Just use:

In `rootApp/settings.gradle`:

```
include ':app' 
include ':myExternalLib'
project(':myExternalLib').projectDir=new   File('pathLibrary')
```

In `app/build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':myExternalLib')
}
```

Pay attention to `myExternalLib`.
You have to use the path of the library inside the other project, **not the root** of the project.
In your case the path is  `rootLibA/moduleA`

Answer (score 0):

No, there would be no code duplication. Gradle will use the class files generated by one project, when compiling the other.

No, there is not a better way - your suggestion is the common practice.

I would use a multi-project build in your case, like Gabriele Mariotti suggests in his answer.